# I am learning programming, I came across Look and Say sequence.I tried to code it in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

Can you please suggest how I could possibly reduce the complexity of this code.Here is the code I wrote in c++.There might be an algorithm for this problem, but I want to improve my coding skills.Thanks.

Here is the sequence that I am trying to generate. 
Eg:1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, ...

1 is read off as "one 1" or 11.

11 is read off as "two 1s" or 21.

21 is read off as "one 2, then one 1" or 1211
Here the function countAndSay takes an integer or the nth number to be generated and returns a string showing the generated nth sequence.

```
#include "string"
#include "iostream"
#include "unordered_map"
using namespace std;

string countAndSay(int n) {
if (n == 1)
    return "1";
int j;
string s = "1";
string temp = "";
unordered_map<char, int> dict;
for (int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j<s.length(); ++j) {

        if (dict.find(s[j]) == dict.end() && j == 0)
            dict[s[j]] = 1;

        else if (dict.find(s[j]) == dict.end()) {
            temp += to_string(dict[s[j - 1]]);
            temp += s[j - 1];
            dict.clear();
            dict[s[j]] = 1;
        }
        else
            dict[s[j]] += 1;
    }

    temp += to_string(dict[s[j - 1]]);
    temp += s[j - 1];
    dict.clear();
    s = temp;
    temp = "";
}

return s;
}
int main()
{
String s=countAndSay(3);
cout<<s;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: A brief description of what the code is trying to achieve would help, I think.

Comment: @AlastairBrown he's trying to generate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence. basically RLE

Comment: Why do i get downvotes on this question. What is wrong with this ?

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah _"You can start by using char arrays ..."_ Wut??

Comment: I have got three downvotes on this question. I am not understanding why. Btw thanks for your comment I shall try using char arrays and see if the runtime decreases.

Comment: @SujithShivaprakash _"I have got three downvotes on this question. I am not understanding why"_ The main reason might be you're missing to provide a [MCVE] in your question.

Comment: @SujithShivaprakash valid reasons for downvotes: you have "I am learning" in the title. Please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask; you don't specify the problem you are trying to solve (just naming it it's not enough)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  i mean `int`-arrays, which are more efficient than `std::unordered_map` in every way (except allocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the number and store it in array or string. loop over this and check if current element is same as previous (0 index based, start from 1 and check arr[i] == arr[i-1]) then increase counter or else print the [i-1] element with counter and reset counter to 1.